# Self-written R package requires up-to-date R

Tags: r, version, package, self

I am experimenting with creating my own R packages. I used the tutorial from this link. Basically, its using `roxygen2` package to create a package "blue print".

The package works properly on my system (R 3.3.0); yet when I asked a friend to test it for me he said he could not load it on an older R version. I reproduced the problem on my system with R 3.0.
Error message, very generic:

> ERROR: this R is version 3.0.0, package 'Dataprep' requires R >= 3.3.0

I'm sure the reason for this problem is trivial, so I would be happy for some advice.

Comment: Please check `Depends` tag in the DESCRIPTION file of package. `Depends` contains the R versions in which the particular package can run for Example `Depends: R (>= 3.2.3)`. See this link for more information http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem.